# Sinch : Know the number of participants in a conference call

Tags: android, rest, sinch, android-sinch-api

I am building a conference calling app using `Sinch` in Android. I can now establish conference calls and add participants to it successfully.

Now I would like to add some capabilities to my app:

1. Know the number of participants at a given time.
2. Mute a particular user.

I was looking into [this link.](https://www.sinch.com/docs/voice/rest/#callingapi). I understand that `Sinch` is giving some `REST` services to achieve the above services. I have never worked with `REST` web services in Android. I also went through the tutorials section and was unable to find a tutorial on how to call a `REST API` end point from Android.

I would like a simple walkthrough or a guide to call `Sinch` REST services from Android, especially to achieve the first capability (know the number of participants).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of this can be done by calling the Sinch REST API from your app.

Refer here : [Link 1](https://www.sinch.com/docs/voice/rest/#GetConferenceInfo)

If you don't know how to use REST API. I recommend using either `Volley` or `Retrofit` to make the network calls. Various tutorials on how to use them both are available on the net. Please refer that.